# Adding session attribute with spring rest template

Tags: junit, resttemplate, spring-test

Following is my Test class which is responsible for testing POST method.

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@ApplicationTest
@WithMockUser("mike")
public class AnalysisRecordParam {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
     MockHttpSession session=new MockHttpSession();
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SCR = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate("operations", "operations");

    @Test
    @Parameters(method= "parametersForSavesCustomer")       
    public void savesCustomer(String name,AnalysisRecordTO analysisRecordTO) throws Exception{          

        AnalysisRecordTO result = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/analysisrecord/", analysisRecordTO, AnalysisRecordTO.class);
        assertNotEquals(null, result);       

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public Object[] parametersForSavesCustomer() {

        Object[] array=null;
        Properties analysisMap=new Properties();
        try {
            analysisMap.load(AbstractJobArgumentProvider.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/analysis-list.properties"));
            Set<Object> set=analysisMap.keySet();
            array=new Object[analysisMap.size()];
            int i=0;
            for(Object key:set){                    
                Object[] arr=new Object[2];
                arr[0]=key.toString();
                String jsonFilePath=(String)analysisMap.get(key);
                AnalysisRecordTO analysis=this.objectMapper.readValue(new File(jsonFilePath), AnalysisRecordTO.class);
                arr[1]=analysis;
                array[i]=arr;
                i++;                    
            }               

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        return array;
   }
}
```

I have one interceptor which looks for CONSUMER_TYPE and CONSUMER_ID in session before forwarding the request.
Code for interceptor is as below :

```
public class ConsumerTypeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    String method = request.getMethod();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(!method.equals("OPTIONS") && (session == null || session.getAttribute("CONSUMER_TYPE") == null || session.getAttribute("CONSUMER_ID") == null)){
        System.out.println("Invalid request");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED, "Invalid login token");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Using Rest template request is given properly but it is denied by interceptor.
I just wanted to know how to set these session attributes?